# Subselect in main query which is not a WHERE clause - subquery() does not work

Tags: sqlalchemy

I need to have a simple subselect as follows,

```
SELECT  ets.agreement_t.id  AS ets_agreement_t_id,
        ...,
        (select max(created_date) from ets.agreement_history_t where agreement_group_id = ets.agreement_t.agreement_group_id AS "LastApprovalDate"),
        ...
```

In SqlAlchemy I created  `.subquery()`:

```
subqueryLastApprovalDate = db_session.query(func.max(AgreementHistoryT.created_date).filter(
                                (AgreementHistoryT.agreement_group_id == AgreementT.agreement_group_id))
                            ).label('lastApprovalDate')).subquery()
```

which is then inserted into the main Select:

```
   agreements = (
        db_session.query(  
                            AgreementT.id,
                            ...
                            subqueryLastApprovalDate,
                            ...
```

but this produces the wrong SQL. It puts my subselect in the FROM clause:

```
SELECT          ets.agreement_t.id,
                ...
                anon_1."lastApprovalDate" AS "anon_1_lastApprovalDate",
                ...
FROM            (
                       SELECT max(ets.agreement_history_t.created_date) filter (WHERE ets.agreement_history_t.agreement_group_id = ets.agreement_t.agreement_group_id
                       ) AS "lastApprovalDate"
                       FROM   ets.agreement_history_t,
                              ets.agreement_t) AS anon_1,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem. For inner selects that are not in the WHERE clause, `select()` is used, **not** `subquery()`. So it had to be

```
subselectLastApprovalDate = select(func.to_char(func.max(AgreementHistoryT.created_date), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                                    ).filter(
                                        (AgreementHistoryT.agreement_group_id == AgreementT.agreement_group_id), 
                                        (AgreementHistoryT.action_taken_type_id.in_([
                                            CONSTANTS.ACTION_TAKEN_TYPE_APPROVED_ID, 
                                            CONSTANTS.ACTION_TAKEN_TYPE_UPDATE_APPROVED_ID
                                        ]))
                                    ).as_scalar()
```

and then

```
db_session.query(
   ...
   subselectLastApprovalDate.label('lastApprovalDate'),
   ...
)
```